# Select first n rows in contentProvider

Tags: android, where-clause, android-contentprovider

I've this select:

```
 final Cursor cursorConversations = getContentResolver().query(
        Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/conversations/" + Uri.encode(mailAddress)),
        null, null, null, BaseColumns._ID + " DESC");

 ContentQueryMap mQueryMap 
        = new ContentQueryMap(cursorConversations, BaseColumns._ID, true, null);
```

With ContentQueyMap I can cache Cursor data and iterate in it also with the Cursor closed (i need it to boost performance).

Now, I want that the select of the Corsor only retrieve the first fifty rows. The solution of looping for 50 times in `mQueryMap.getRows().entrySet()` is not right: I don't want that mQueryMap gets all the rows of the Cursor, but only the first fifty.

Any idea? Does exist a where clause to get only first n rows?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do

```
final Cursor cursorConversations = getContentResolver().query(
    Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/conversations/" + Uri.encode(mailAddress)),
    null, null, null, BaseColumns._ID + " DESC " + " LIMIT 5");
```

"LIMIT x" after your SORT.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much! @Chris please do think you could help me here :http://goo.gl/MAjgTh

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Table_Name LIMIT 5;

That's valid for sqlite.  Try adding "LIMIT 5" to your where clause. (I have not tried)

Comment: Won't go. And if I put in in the "sort clause parameter" ddms throws an exception: "sortOrder MUST be empty"... (why??)